# https with jython2.7 + trusting all certificates does not work. Result: httplib.BadStatusLine

Tags: ssl, https, jython

> **UPDATE**: Problem related to bug in jython 2.7b1. See bug report: http://bugs.jython.org/issue2021. jython-coders are working on a fix!

After changing to jython2.7beta1 from Jython2.5.3 I am no longer able to read content of webpages using SSL, http and "trusting all certificates". The response from the https-page is always an empty string, resulting in httplib.BadStatusLine exception from httplib.py in Jython.

I need to be able to read from a webpage which requires authentication and do not want to setup any certificate store since I must have portability. Therefore my solution is to use the excellent implementation provided by http://tech.pedersen-live.com/2010/10/trusting-all-certificates-in-jython/

Example code is detailed below. Twitter might not be the best example, since it does not require certificate trusting; but the result is the same with or without the decorator.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
from javax.net.ssl import TrustManager, X509TrustManager
from jarray import array
from javax.net.ssl import SSLContext

class TrustAllX509TrustManager(X509TrustManager):

    # Define a custom TrustManager which will blindly
    # accept all certificates
    def checkClientTrusted(self, chain, auth):
        pass

    def checkServerTrusted(self, chain, auth):
        pass

    def getAcceptedIssuers(self):
        return None

# Create a static reference to an SSLContext which will use
# our custom TrustManager
trust_managers = array([TrustAllX509TrustManager()], TrustManager)
TRUST_ALL_CONTEXT = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
TRUST_ALL_CONTEXT.init(None, trust_managers, None)

# Keep a static reference to the JVM's default SSLContext for restoring
# at a later time
DEFAULT_CONTEXT = SSLContext.getDefault()


def trust_all_certificates(f):
    # Decorator function that will make it so the context of the decorated
    # method will run with our TrustManager that accepts all certificates

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        # Only do this if running under Jython
        if 'java' in sys.platform:
            from javax.net.ssl import SSLContext
            SSLContext.setDefault(TRUST_ALL_CONTEXT)
            print "SSLContext set to TRUST_ALL"
            try:
                res = f(*args, **kwargs)
                return res
            finally:
                SSLContext.setDefault(DEFAULT_CONTEXT)
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

#@trust_all_certificates
def read_page(host):
    import httplib 
    print "Host: " + host
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
    conn.set_debuglevel(1)
    conn.request('GET', '/example')
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print response.read()

read_page("twitter.com")
```

This results in:

```
Host: twitter.com
send: 'GET /example HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: twitter.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\n\r\n'
reply: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jytest.py", line 62, in <module>
    read_page("twitter.com")
  File "jytest.py", line 59, in read_page
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/Users/erikiveroth/Workspace/Procera/sandbox/jython/jython2.7.jar/Lib/httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
  File "/Users/erikiveroth/Workspace/Procera/sandbox/jython/jython2.7.jar/Lib/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
  File "/Users/erikiveroth/Workspace/Procera/sandbox/jython/jython2.7.jar/Lib/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Changing back to jython2.5.3 gives me parseable output from twitter.

Have any of you seen this before? Can not find any bug-tickets on jython project page about this nor can I understand what changes could result in this behaviour (more than maybe #1309, but I do not understand if it is related to my problem).

Cheers